# call function fron ruby controller in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to perform an action write to file in controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:

```
def fileopen
        my_file = File.new("public/CHNAME1.txt","w") 
        my_file.write "\tfasf"
        my_file.close

    end
```

(it work well when i define it in helper and call it in view.)

in myview.html.erb, i want some thing like  How can I do that? I tried in application.js

```
function readfile() {
  alert('readfile work')
  $.ajax({
  alert('ajax work')
      url: "/fileopen",
      type: "POST",
      ##don't know what to to to call fileopen
      }
  });
}
```

routes.rb

```
match '/fileopen', to:'static_pages#fileopen', via: 'get'
```

and it's seem nothing happen. Only the first alert work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax error, try this:

```
function readfile() {
  alert('readfile work');
  $.ajax({
      url: "/fileopen",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(){
          alert('ajax work');
      }
  });
}
```

I don't know ruby but route is on "GET" request and you are making "POST" request:

```
match '/fileopen', to:'static_pages#fileopen', via: 'get' // should be via: 'post'?
```

Comment: tks, it helps me a lot , can I send some variable by Ajax, such as
function readfile() {
  alert('readfile work');
  $.ajax({
      url: "/fileopen",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(){
         senddata($variable1);
         senddata($variable2);
      }
  });
}
and in fileopen I can use 
def fileopen
        my_file = File.new("public/CHNAME1.txt","w") 
        my_file.write "$variable1" "$variable2"
        my_file.close

    end

Comment: You can send data like this:

`$.ajax({
      url: "/fileopen",
      type: "POST",
      data: { parameterName: 'parameterValue' }
      success: function(){
          alert('ajax work');
      }
  });`. read documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

You can not use alert within ajax, If you want to use it then use in success and error methods